# Get jquery variable by id with @Html.Raw

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to store a jquery variable. I want to find the id by using @Html.Raw and add controlls to the class with the same name but so far I am only getting unrecognized expression

```
var $a = $('#@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i).Replace("\\", "\\\\'").Replace("'", "\\'"))');
var $b = $('.@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i).Replace("\\", "\\\\'").Replace("'", "\\'"))');
$a.click(function () {
  $b.attr('controls', '')
});
```

Comment: Look at the actual output and debug the JS from there.

Comment: *Why* are there `'`s in your IDs? Just use: `$("#@Html.Raw(ce.ElementAt(i))")`

Answer (score -2):

replaced

```
var $a = $('#@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i).Replace("\\", "\\\\'").Replace("'", "\\'"))'); 
var $b = $('.@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i).Replace("\\", "\\\\'").Replace("'", "\\'"))');
```

with

```
var $a = $(document.getElementById('@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i))'));
var $b = $(document.getElementsByClassName('@Html.Raw(c.ElementAt(i))'));
```